# Having trouble updating a document in Vue JS using Firebase's Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a simple single page web app using Vue JS (Vue Cli 3) with Firebase's Firestore as the back-end database. I've managed to add, and delete records with ease. I'm running into an issue when trying to 'update' a user's details.

My code for this function is as follows:

```
saveEditUser() {
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', this.form.email)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        doc.ref.update({
          email: this.form.email
        })
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully updated the record')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
    })
}
```

Some things that I've discovered during my attempts at debugging this:

- This is **not** a scope issue where 'this' in the this.form.email is not available inside the forEach loop.
- I thought this could be the case and so I declared a 'const vm = this' before the loop and tried to use vm.form.email, but no dice.
- Also, when I try to update the email field to a simple string like 'abc' instead of a dynamic value such as this.form.email, it works!

After several spent hours on this ridiculous problem, I am officially stumped folks. Please send help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR***: the OP was updating a record with the same value, hence nothing appeared to change in the Firestore DB. However, in his code, there was the need to return the promise returned by the single asynchronous operation (or by the set of asynchronous operations)

Since your are **potentially** going to execute several asynchronous operations to the database in parallel (using the `update()` method, which return a promise, see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update)) , you need to use **Promise.all()**, as follows.

```
saveEditUser() {
  const email = this.form.email;
  const= promises = [];
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', email )
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        promises.push(
            doc.ref.update({
                email: email   //Actually the problems comes from here, see below
             })
        );
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully updated the record')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
    })
}
```

If you are 100% sure your query will return only one doc you could update the doc directly, but then you have to return the promise returned by `update()`, as follows:

```
saveEditUser() {
  const email = this.form.email;
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', email)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      return snap.docs[0].ref.update({
          email: email
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully updated the record')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
    })
}
```

Note: by declaring the `email` const at the beginning of the function, you should not encounter any problem of context anymore.

---

**Update following our comments and discussion:**

Actually you are updating with the SAME value of `email`. So it is normal you don't see any result. Just try to update with another value, like in the following code:

```
saveEditUser() {
  const email = this.form.email;
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', email)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      return snap.docs[0].ref.update({
          email: 'john.doe@gmail.com'
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successfully updated the record')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
    })
}
```

If you want to test with a value from your form, just use two fields: one with the value to query and one with the new value, like:

```
<input v-model="form.mail" placeholder="mail to search for">
<input v-model="form.newMail" placeholder="new email">

.....

    saveEditUser() {
      const emailToQuery = this.form.email;
      const newEmail = this.form.newMail;
      db.collection('users')
        .where('email', '==', emailToQuery )
        .get()
        .then(snap => {
          return snap.docs[0].ref.update({
              email: newEmail 
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Successfully updated the record')
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: That made a lot of sense to me, but unfortunately, it didn't seem to have any affect on the result. No errors or anything in the log (I get a success, same as I was before), but the record does not update. EDIT: Trying your second solution now.

Comment: Nope, security rules are wide open (just learning at the moment, so didn't bother with it) https://i.imgur.com/s9Qxwck.png

Comment: With your second solution, I assume you meant snap.docs[0].ref.update - anyway, didn't work with the following error given: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Comment: Is value of this.form.email correct? What if you do `console.log(this.form.email);`?

Comment: Yup, it is correct. console.log(this.form.email) shows me the email address that is bound to the v-model of the email field in the edit form. Showing correctly in both places.

Comment: Yes!  `snap.docs[0].ref.update()`! Apparently your query does not return any doc. What if you do `.then(snap => {console.log(snap.size);})`

Comment: I get back 1 - it is definitely returning the record because as stated in my initial problem statement, when I would simply change the email: this.form.email to email: 'abcd@def.com' , it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184266/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-kopty).

Comment: Actually you are updating with the **SAME** value of `email`! So it is normal you don't see any result! Just try to update with another value!